# output 2 string in one function

Tags: php, function, echo

Ok, I must admit, I am a rather PHP noob who struggles with what seems to me a simple issue.

What i want to accomplish is that I can put 2 strings in 1 function and echo them in different places.

In common.php i have this:

```
<?
function printHeader($titel)    {
?>
```

Later on in the file i echo it between

And in index.php i have this:

```
<?
include "common.php";
printHeader('this is my title');
?>
```

This works alright.... now what i like to do is to ad another String to the printheader to not only echo the title but also the H1, so i tried this:

Common:

```
<?
function printHeader($titel . $headtitle)   {
?>
```

Index:

```
<?
include "common.php";
printHeader('This is my title!' . 'This is my H1');
?>
```

This does not seem to work. Are there any phpsavvy guys out here who can help me wit this simple problem?

If it is not to much to ask I would also like to Echo some standard value if $headtitle is empty, but that is waaaay of my league :)

**EDIT: thanks to you guys the first problem is fixed. Now i want to try and fix the IF empty part. So I came up with this**:

```
<?
function printHeader($titel, $headtitle)    {
    if (empty($headtitle)) {
    echo 'title is empty'; }
?>
```

html goes here + this: `<h1><?=$headtitle; ?></h1>` more HTML

```
<? } ?>
```

This does not seem to work...

any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance,
A simple webdesigner ;)

Comment: Here, function printHeader($titel . $headtitle), arguments are passed with commas between not dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function arguments should seperate by a comma `,`

```
function printHeader($titel , $headtitle)
```

And obviously same for calling,

```
printHeader('This is my title!' , 'This is my H1');
```

Comment: it was that simple!!!

Do you also know how i can fix the part that IF $headtitle is empty it outputs a standard value? If i know that then i am really really happy :)

Comment: The code you tried should work. Show your calling part when it does not work.

Comment: <?
include "common.php";
printHeader('the title' , '');
?>

as you can see i left the second part empty so it should echo "title is empty"

Comment: With some minor adjustments to your code (placing the if snippet elsewhere) i got it to work. Really gratefull!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to seperate the second the argument by , like this

```
function printHeader($titel , $headtitle)
```

and change while calling also

```
printHeader("string1","String2");
```

or keep like this

```
function printHeader($titel){..... }


printHeader("string1"."String2");
```

so `$title1` will have appended string.